# React Native: How to trigger react native app when certain app is opened?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

**Use-case**: I am making an app that is useful for controlling distraction. For example, when user opens YouTube, my Ract-Native app comes in foreground, asks few questions and upon correct answer user can continue to browse YouTube.

So I want to detect (or listen) which app is in the foreground or which app is opened now, so that my React-Native can come in the foreground.

Any solution is welcomed that serves this use-case.